# bulk update mongo records

Tags: php, sql, mongodb, nosql

I have a large sharded mongo collection (totaling around 16 million records) that I need to go through and add an attribute to. On the current server, writing a script to loop through these and check if the attribute is missing and write the new attribute will take probably at least a week. The new attribute is just an existing attribute in upper case.

Right now I'm selecting the records without the attribute, then looping through the result set with PHP, adding the attribute to the array, and re-saving the record.

This can't be the most efficient way to do it-- is there no equivalent to

```
UPDATE mytable SET attribute = UPPER(old_attribute) WHERE attribute IS NULL
```

in mongo?

Answer (score 0):

There is a $set with update query, you can try this

```
db.collection.update({attribute: null}, {$set:{"attribute":value}})
```

Comment: @Rohit-- thanks, but as stated in the post the attribute that needs to be set is an existing attribute, only in uppercase.

Comment: you can try like db.collection.update({attribute: null}, {$set:{"attribute":value.toUpperCase()}}) hope it will work :)